# A "catch-all" for SFINAE functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I am trying to make a typed compare function that do some customized comparison for different types.

```
 #include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
bool typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return lhs == rhs; // default case, use ==
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return (lhs - rhs) < 1e-10;
}

int main()
{
    typedCompare(1, 1);
    typedCompare(1.0, 1.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I have a special version for `double` that compare the difference with a small amount (please ignore the fact that I did not use `std::abs()`). I have a few other custom types that I need to do some special comparison, and I cannot change their `==` operator for some reason.

Besides, I still want to have a "catch-all" style function that employs the `==` operator. My problem is that when trying to compile this code snippet the compiler complains about that `typedCompare(1.0, 1.0)` is ambiguous, it can choose either of the two functions provided.

Why? And how could I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you just use an overloaded function?

Comment: What's wrong with just excluding the `float` from the first template?
`typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type`

Comment: @NorbertLange 1) I want to learn more about SFINAE and 2) I want to avoid the situation where I have to define two functions for double and float

Comment: @YePhIcK I have other types I want to specialize, that would not scale?

Comment: I see. You are correct - that would not scale (and the answer below doesn't seem to address your issue either, I suppose)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why?

In short, you use SFINAE incorrectly so both function templates are valid when you call `typedCompare` for doubles.

> And how could I resolve this issue?

In this particular case, fix SFINAE to make it work correctly:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return lhs == rhs; // default case, use ==
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return (lhs - rhs) < 1e-10;
}
```

Please note, that this solution is not that good in terms of customization for many types. Another way is to use tag dispatching:

```
struct floating_point_tag {};
// other tags

template <typename T>
bool typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, floating_point_tag) {
    return (lhs - rhs) < 1e-10;
}

// implementations for other tags

template <typename T>
bool typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    if (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
        return typedCompare(lhs, rhs, floating_point_tag{});
    }

    // other checks here

    return lhs == rhs;
}
```

Finally, with C++17 you might make use of `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
bool typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
        return (lhs - rhs) < 1e-10;
    } else { // add other if-else here
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
}
```

Comment: But, imagine if we have 10 types that I specialize, then the first function's condition will be explode?

Comment: @dorafmon I've added some other ideas, would be great to know your opinion :)

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer, I don't have C++17 at this moment but I think that solution is most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code in your question is that when the floating point `typedCompare()` is SFINAE enabled, collide with the general version because the compiler can't prefer one version over the other.

To solve this problem, I suggest you another way, based on template partial specialization (available only with structs and classes, so need a helper `struct`)

If you define an helper `struct` as follows

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct typedCompareHelper
 {
   static constexpr bool func (T const & lhs, T const & rhs)
    { return lhs == rhs; } // default case, use == 
 };

template <typename T>
struct typedCompareHelper<T,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
 {
   static constexpr bool func (T const & lhs, T const & rhs)
    { return (lhs - rhs) < 1e-10; }
 };
```

you avoid the ambiguity problem because the `typedCompareHelper` specialization in more specialized of the generic one.

You can simply add more specializations for different special cases making only attention in avoiding collisions (different specializations of the same level that apply over the same type).

Your `typedCompare()` become simply

```
template <typename T>
bool typedCompare (T const & lhs, T const & rhs)
 { return typedCompareHelper<T>::func(lhs, rhs); }
```

Comment: This is a bit like the other answer in the respect of tag dispatch, but it suits my purpose very well. Thanks!

Comment: @dorafmon - yes: not really different: tag dispatching is another good way to solve the problem that arise from the lack of function partial specialization.

Answer (score 1):

I like both the solution from @max66 with a helper template and the multiple solutions from @Edgar Rokyan.

Here is another approach that can be used for what you want using a helper template function.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// elipsis version is at the bottom of the overload resolution priority.
// it will only be used if nothing else matches the overload.
void typeCompare_specialized(...)
{
  std::cout << "SHOULD NEVER BE CALLED!!!\n";
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
typeCompare_specialized(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
  std::cout << "floating-point version\n";
  return (lhs - rhs) < 1e-10;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type
typeCompare_specialized(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
  std::cout << "integral version\n";
  return lhs == rhs;
}

template <typename T>
auto typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
  -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<bool,decltype(typeCompare_specialized(lhs, rhs))>::value,bool>::type
{
  return typeCompare_specialized(lhs, rhs);
}

template <typename T>
auto typedCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
  -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<bool,decltype(typeCompare_specialized(lhs, rhs))>::value,bool>::type
{
  std::cout << "catch-all version\n";
  return lhs == rhs;
}

int main()
{
  typedCompare(1, 1);
  typedCompare(1.0, 1.0);
  typedCompare(std::string("hello"), std::string("there"));

  return 0;
}
```

Running the above program will yield the following output:

```
integral version
floating-point version
catch-all version
```

Again, I would prefer to use one of the previous answers mentioned.  I include this possibility for completeness.

I would also like to add that you should make sure your `typeCompare_specialized()` template versions should not have any overlap, otherwise you could get a compiler error declaring that there are multiple candidate overloads to use.